Visual Studio 2022 - indent closing function paren with beginning of argument
In Microsoft driver code (even the driver templates included in VS), they frequently format the function signature like this:
VOID
EvtIoStop(
    _In_ WDFQUEUE Queue,
    _In_ WDFREQUEST Request,
    _In_ ULONG ActionFlags
    )

Notice how the closing paren is aligned with the start of the arguments.
When I auto format, it keeps removing all space before the paren.
How can I stop it from doing that? I have messed with many options under Options -> C/C++ -> Code Style but none have any effect on this behavior.

This code style is from some 3rd-party extension.You may want to check on this:
Resharper closing parenthesis indentation on function with multiple arguments
